# C RC4 super weird behavior

Tags: c, encryption, rc4-cipher, stream-cipher

so I found the implementation of RC4 in pure C, which I was using on my website. It was working super good except when I input a 6 characters string. Then I get the Internal Error Page. Figured out that only this length causes a problem.

1.Crypt.c

```
unsigned char S[256];
unsigned int i, j;
void swap(unsigned char *s, unsigned int i, unsigned int j) {
unsigned char temp = s[i];
s[i] = s[j];
s[j] = temp;
}

/* KSA */
void rc4_init(unsigned char *key, unsigned int key_length) {
for (i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    S[i] = i;

for (i = j = 0; i < 256; i++) {
    j = (j + key[i % key_length] + S[i]) & 255;
    swap(S, i, j);
}

i = j = 0;
}

/* PRGA */
unsigned char rc4_output() {
i = (i + 1) & 255;
j = (j + S[i]) & 255;

swap(S, i, j);

return S[(S[i] + S[j]) & 255];
}

char *rc4_e(char *text, size_t text_length)
{
char *dup=(char *)malloc(text_length * sizeof(char));
strcpy(dup,text);
unsigned char *vector[2] = {"key", dup}; 
    int y;
    rc4_init(vector[0], strlen((char*)vector[0]));
char *out=(char *)malloc(text_length * sizeof(char) );
char *ptr=out;
    for (y = 0; y < strlen((char*)vector[1]); y++)
       ptr += sprintf(ptr,"%02X",vector[1][y] ^ rc4_output());
*(ptr + 1) = '\0';
return out;
}
```

2.Main

```
#define SIZE 1000
char* pass=(char*)malloc(SIZE * sizeof(char));
char *RC4_pass=(char*)malloc(getSize(pass) * sizeof(char)); 
 strcpy(RC4_pass,rc4_e(pass,sizeof(pass)));
```

Any advice or thoughts are extremely welcome. Just want to know whether it is the function itself that is bad or the rest of my C code.
Thank!

Comment: make a command line test function and run it under a debugger

Comment: regarding calls to malloc(): 1) do not cast the returned value  2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure successful operation  3) do not use 'sizeof(char)'  in the parameter list as that value is always 1 and all it does is clutter the code.

Comment: this code: 'sizof(pass)'  will always be 4, because pass is defined as a char*  I doubt that is actually what you want

Comment: when #define'ing a numeric value, always wrap the numeric value in parens '(' and ')'  to avoid several kinds of text replacement problems

Comment: to make the code much more readable by us humans, please indent (say 4 spaces) after every opening brace '{'  and un-indent before every closing brace '}'.  Do not use tabs for indenting as each editor/wordprocessor has the tabs stops/tab width set differently.

Comment: the 'i' and 'j' parameters mask the global 'i' and 'j' variables.  This is a very bad programming practice.  suggest enabling all warnings when compiling, so these kinds of problems are caught/fixed now rather than spending many many hours debugging any related problems.  the correct parameter for gcc would be '-Wshadow'

Answer (score 2):

There is a problem with this line:

```
char *dup=(char *)malloc(text_length * sizeof(char));
```

You forgot to add an extra byte for the terminating `'\0'` at the end of the string. So at the very next line:

```
strcpy(dup,text);
```

you're committing an out-of-bounds access in the array `dup`, which is causing undefined behaviour.

Comment: Yeah this one is an error that I should've fixed, so thanks for pointing out. I think my error was not only in this function, but also in the fact that I combined it with a base64, which may be the actual cause of error. Thanks again!